# Go to another page after files have completed uploading in dropzone.js v4.0

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

```
<form action="jay-upload.php"
  class="dropzone"
  id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>

<script>
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    init: function() {
    this.on("success", function() {
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";
                                   });
                             }
                      };
    </script>
```

I am trying to do it like this but its not working. :(

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? Also, "queuecomplete" might be a better event. That gets fired after all files have been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, it may work for you.

```
this.on("success", function() {
     if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
    window.location.href = 'http://example.com/new_url';
  }
```